# How to write pseudo code for median function?

Tags: python, median

I recognise that Pseudo code is relative to our own abbreviations but I am having a struggling converting this to Pseudo code:

```
    median = (sum(s[n//2-1:n//2+1])/2.0, s[n//2])[n % 2] if n else None
```

Could anyone lend a hand?

Answer (score 0):

This is not pseudo code, it is valid Python code. Just that it has been condensed to the point where it isn't very easy to read for those unfamiliar with the syntax.

`if n else None` is an expression that will only evaluate the earlier part if `n` is `True`. Since `n` seems to be the length of the list `s`, it will evaluate to `True` as long as it is not `0` (or `None`). Thus, the `median` will be `None` if the list is empty.

`(sum(s[n//2-1:n//2+1])/2.0, s[n//2])[n % 2]` is evaluating the median based on whether `n` is even or odd (this is by definition of the median). `n%2` is 0 for even and 1 for odd, so they have calculated both median possibilities and put them in a `tuple` and are accessing the index through this result.

For the even case, median is average of central 2 items, hence `sum()/2.0`. `n//2` will perform integer division and `s[(n//2)-1:(n//2)+1]` will select those 2 items (`end` index is excluded in slices).

For the odd case, the median is directly the center item `s[n//2]`.

You can definitely rewrite this to be more readable if you spread it across a few lines instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  So far i have this : median is equal to the sum of s where n is divided to an integer by 2-1 : to n divided to an integer by 2+1 then divided by 2. But seems wrong